# NLTK: Get word from Synset ID

Tags: nltk

Using NLTK is there a way of getting the word and its POS given the Synset ID?

I have a set if Synset ID and their corresponding domains, I need a way to extract label using the SynsetID
Thanks

Ankit

Comment: possible duplicate of [wordnet - synset offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077641/wordnet-synset-offset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now with nltk 3.2.4 (and probably already a bit before), you can simply use the method [synset_from_pos_and_offset(pos, offset)](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.WordNetCorpusReader.synset_from_pos_and_offset) from the [nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet module](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#module-nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet)

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
wordnet.synset_from_pos_and_offset('n',2403454)
```